# What is the difference between these two statements

Tags: c, boolean, boolean-expression

I want to know what is the difference between these two statements in C. Are they same? Any logical proof whether they are same or not.

```
if (!(b[i]&&c[i+1]&&c[i+2]&&d[i+3]))
```

and:

```
if (((b[i] == 0|| c[i+1] == 0)|| c[i+2] == 0)|| d[i+3] == 0)
```

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws these two are the same. I think you are lucky and even the evaluation order is the same here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they will both evaluate to the same result.

If either of those values is `0` than the expression will return true and enter the if-statement(barring the missing parens at the end)

as far as proofs go, that is more or less DeMorgan's law

http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese570/Boolean_Identities.pdf

Answer (score 1):

They are the same! For some proof you can read about [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)